# How can I configure Linux kernel without menuconfig or similar tools?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

For some reasons I couldn't launch menuconfig in my host. I'm using Yocto build system. I want to know how to configure the kernel manually to add and remove some drivers. There are a lot of defconfig and Kconfig files, how to know which defconfig file is used by the kernel? And what's the difference between Kconfig and defconfig files?

Comment: It chooses defconfig based on arch and other params. You can do make config, oldconfig or xconfig.

Comment: On Yocto the special merge configuration mechanism is in use. No need to do anything special, just add options you need as configuration excerpts, Yocto build will generate proper configuration automatically. (@stark JFYI)

Comment: by excerpts you mean .cfg files right?

Comment: and where should we add it? to kernel recipe or u-boot recipe? because I found the same CONFIG_X defined in both kernel and uboot sources

Comment: Kernel recipe is for kernel, U-Boot is for U-Boot. Depends in what you want to (seems you want the kernel one, so you have to add to the kernel recipe). U-Boot and kernel are using same build system and some option may have same or similar names (because U-Boot is heavily leveraged by existing kernel code base). (**HInt**: when answering to a comment on SO use `@username` to notify person whom you replied to)

Comment: @0andriy thank you for you response, my last question before marking your response as accepted is the follow: If I want to remove a driver from my distribution should I modify the kernel or the bootloader part?

Comment: Highly depends on two things: 1) what you imply under _remove_: binary module or its source code or something else; 2) if this module plays a crucial role at boot time you need to be careful on the action, otherwise you may end up with non-bootable / non-functional system.